# How does a consumption shock decrease the real interest rate?

Tags: macroeconomics

If prices/wages are flexible, with a negative shock to consumption, for example, I have heard that the real interest rate should fall to keep the demand constant (since consumption is decreasing in the interest rate), but I am confused as to how this would happen. If prices decrease, then it seems like consumption would increase, but I don't know where to go from there.

Does it have to do with a response from the financial system?

Comment: Re: "real interest rate should fall" By itself, or do you mean the central bank would do this? Lower consumption typically lowers inflation... so the real interest rate goes up all other things saying the same.

Comment: I've read that in world with flexible prices (neoclassical model), the central bank wouldn't be able to do anything anyways and the real interest rate would fall on its own.

Comment: Where did you read that? (It sounds like an Austrian theory to me.)